# Set today's date and hide future dates using JQuery

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I am new to JQuery. I am trying to set today's date using datepicker and also trying to hide future dates. But I don't know how to do?

`$("#datepickerto").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
 $("#datepickerto").datepicker({maxDate: new Date()});`

I tried above ways but its not working. Either of them is working correctly but how to make both work at a time?

Comment: This worked for me

$("#datepickerfrom").datepicker();

var d = new Date();

var currDay = d.getDate();

var currMonth = d.getMonth() + 1;

var currYear = d.getFullYear();

$("#datepickerto").datepicker({ maxDate: new Date() }).val(currMonth + "/" + currDay + "/" + currYear);

var dateObject = $("#datepickerto").datepicker("getDate");

var dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", dateObject);

$("#datepickerto").val(dateString);

Answer (score 0):

`datepicker("setDate" ...)` is calling a method, meaning the datepicker must have been previously initialized in order for this to work.

`datepicker({maxDate: ...})` on the other hand, is *initializing* the datepicker, and must happen before any methods are used.

You must remove any previous initialization of the datepicker, and you can then combine the two functions (the initialization with a maxDate, and the setDate method) to one line, as follows:

```
$("#datepickerto").datepicker({maxDate: '0'}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: I forgot to attach the complete code. I have initialized the datepicker first and tried to set the date.
As per your code, its not hiding future dates but its setting today's date.

Comment: See my edit. I have modified the `maxDate` portion, as upon research, it seems like you can use `'0'` to indicate a MaxDate of "0 days in the future". Additionally, I believe you should include your `maxdate` option *when you initialize* the datepicker, not afterwards. The setDate must happen afterwards.

Comment: This worked for me

'$("#datepickerfrom").datepicker();

var d = new Date();

var currDay = d.getDate();

var currMonth = d.getMonth() + 1;

var currYear = d.getFullYear();

$("#datepickerto").datepicker({ maxDate: new Date() }).val(currMonth + "/" + currDay + "/" + currYear);

var dateObject = $("#datepickerto").datepicker("getDate");

var dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", dateObject);

$("#datepickerto").val(dateString);'